# Как обратиться к родительскому элементу после использования document.addEventListener('click',e => function(){})?

Tags: javascript, html

```
document.addEventListener('click',e => function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

После использования данного метода возвращается конкретный (самый дочерний) элемент, на который нажал пользователь. Как можно обратиться к родителям этого элемента?

Comment: В общем и целом - можно использовать свойство `parentElement` либо метод `closest('any-selector')`. А относительно вопроса - задача не ясна (желательно добавить деталей).

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, минимальный фрагмент DOM, где указан этот самый дочерний элемент и целевой (для вас) элемент, который вы хотите получить внутри функции-обработчика события.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
addEventListener(`click`, e => {
  console.log(e.target.parentElement);
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

div:before {
  content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">
      <div class="d">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```